# Calling a C DLL from Fortran

Tags: c, dll, fortran

I have created a DLL in the C language with __declspec(dllexport) VLENCODER f(...); and I want to call it from Fortran using the iso_c_binding features. I have declared the following interface:

```
function create_vlencoder_c(appKey) bind(C, name="create_vlencoder")
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none         
    type(c_ptr) :: create_vlencoder_c
    character(len=1, kind=c_char), intent(in) :: appKey(*)
end function
```

But, at link time, the compiler complains about the symbol _create_vlencoder not being found. Obviously, dependency walker tells me that there is no underscore in front of my name in the DLL. How do I prevent the Fortran compiler to add an underscore to the name of my C function?

PS: I am using the Intel compilers for both C and Fortran on Windows.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Namely you must show how the interface is used at the call site.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I am more of a unix user and not used to Visual Studio. The Fortran code was 32-bit and the C code was 64-bit which leads to a difference of decoration, and hence the problem.